# I've made a bill pay for my credit card after my statement was ready. Now my balance is doubled minus from begining

Tags: credit-card

I got my statement at 21 of December, but was at flight, and I had -35.5 USD balance on my credit card. Next day (22) I made a payment (by 2 transactions) to hit it to 0, and set payment to be processed at next day (23). But now my credit card shows me there is -71 USD on balance while transactions from other account show -35 USD withdrawal. What happened? There is no additional notifications and whatever. Just 2 transactions on both accounts for same amount (same Bank).

Comment: Man this problem could so trivially be averted if it were just decided to universally make negative numbers mean "you owe something" and positive numbers mean "you own something". None of this credit/debit bs to negative the negative.

Comment: It's not that easy, @Alexander-ReinstateMonica - the credit card company _owes something_, so they made it negative... for anything that is 'owed' there is always the other side who 'owns' it, so depending on who looks at the statement, one of them sees it 'the wrong way around'.

Comment: @Aganju On a user-facing web interface of a bank, it's entirely clear that the more important perspective is that of the end user.

Answer (score 31):

You had a $35.50 credit for whatever reason. You got the statement, paid another $35.50, now have a $71 credit. Go fill up the gas tank a couple times and don’t worry about this. (Note: for those of us who use the card regularly, these credits, the potential of the bank owing us money, doesn't last long.)

Comment: Correct. A negative balance means you overpaid it already. Now you overpaid it twice.